# Doble negativa y absoluto

Tags: negación

¿Qué significa la frase "con un negativo nada en absoluto"? Aparece en el contexto de [este párrafo](https://www.biblia.work/diccionarios/g4487/):

> ῥῆμα
>
> jréma
>
> de G4483; declaración (individual, colectivo o específicamente); por implicación asunto o tema (específicamente de narración, orden o disputa); con un negativa nada en absoluto: asunto, mal, palabra.

Comment: Buscando un contexto ampliado para ese texto, lo único que he encontrado son repeticiones de ese mismo párrafo en varias webs. Me da la sensación de que ahí falta o bien letras en cursiva para separar palabras que se usan metalingüísticamente o bien una traducción correcta de un texto que originalmente estaba en otro idioma. Tal y como está redactado el párrafo yo no le veo mucho sentido.

Comment: This  word rhema in the BIble was translated from the English lexicon by some guy called Strong: ῥῆμα rhēma, hray'-mah; from G4483; an utterance (individually, collectively or specially),; by implication, a matter or topic (especially of narration, command or dispute); with a negative naught whatever:—+ evil, + nothing, saying, word.///https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=kjv&strongs=g4487

Comment: Here is a Strong concordance: http://www.eliyah.com/cgi-bin/strongs.cgi?file=greeklexicon&isindex=4483//It was published in 1890 so the English is old fashioned.

Answer (score 4):

Se trata de una mala traducción al español, posiblemente realizada por un sistema automático. Aquí tienes [el original](https://biblehub.com/greek/4487.htm) inglés:

> **4487. rhéma**
>
> ```
> Strong's Exhaustive Concordance
> ```
>
> saying, word.
>
> From rheo; an utterance (individually, collectively or specially),; by implication, a matter or topic (especially of narration, command or dispute); with a negative naught whatever -- + evil, + nothing, saying, word.

Básicamente te está diciendo que la palabra del griego clásico *ῥῆμα* significa "dicho", "palabra", pero que en un contexto negativo puede implicar el concepto de "nada". O al menos eso es lo que yo entiendo, a juzgar por el resto de la documentación del enlace.

Comment: Yes, I just added more stuff under the question.